# File won't open in Chrome or Firefox, file name in URL changes to "0"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried searching for "file name changes to 0 in browser" both in Google and here, but got nowhere.  This is a simple file which suddenly stopped opening. I can't even get at the inspector to troubleshoot it. Undo/redo history is lost, so that will not help.  I'm guessing it's a simple mistake, but I have NEVER seen this before.

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>JS Animated Navigation Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script>
        <!--
        var location = 0; 
        var bar = document.getElementById("bar1");

        function myMove()
        {
        // if (id != 0) clearInterval(id);
        location = -144; 
        // if (location != -144) return; // don't execute onmouseover while previous onmouseover is still running. 
        id = setInterval(move, 1);
        }  

        function move() 
        {
            location++; 
            bar.style.left = location + 'px'; 
            if (location == 300)
            {
                clearInterval(id);    
                id = setInterval(moveback, 1); 
            }  
        }

        function moveback()
        {
            location--; 
            bar.style.left = location + 'px';    
            if (location == -144)  
            {
                clearInterval(id);    
                // id = setInterval(move, 1); 
            }  
        }

    -->
    </script>
    <style>
    #container
    {
        width: 600px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        background: white;
    }
    #bar1
    {
        width: 150px;
        height: 30px;   
        position: absolute;
        left: -144px; 
        background-color: white;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<p>
<button onclick="myMove()">Click Me</button>
</p>

<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate"><img src="imageGalleryBar.png" alt="Image Gallery" width="150" height="30" id="bar1" onmouseover="myMove()" /></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: <!-- is invalid javascript, that is a html tag use /* ..code.. */ instead

Comment: @Noface The <!-- and --> tokens are permitted within scripts (but not modules) by Annex B: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-html-like-comments. There is some corresponding special casing in HTML’s grammar between script tags.

Comment: ok but they still shouldn't use them it is for legacy support supposedly

Comment: I would really like to see a change made on SO that requires down votes to be supported by documentation that a question was a duplicate or otherwise not permitted.  This was/is a legitimate question, and (as suspected) a simple mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the variable name `location` as it is a reserved word; what you're actually doing is setting the `window.location` variable to `0`.

Rename it, or put it in a namespace or object.

Comment: this is the solution - this will send you to the empty page "0" which is as is described in your question

Comment: @Lawrence Unfortunately, "location" didn't show up as a reserved work in Notepad++, and I completely missed it.  **Thank you very much.**